# Proving that $(uv + wz) \leq \sqrt{(u^2 + w^2) (v^2 + z^2)} \implies (u+v)^2 + (w+z)^2 \leq \left(\sqrt{u^2 + w^2} + \sqrt{v^2 + z^2}\right)^2.$

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

In the book "Metric Spaces" by Micheal O Searcoid, the proof given as the answer for question Q1.4 includes:

> For all real numbers $u,v,w,z$, we have $(wv - uz)^2 \geq 0$, so that $2uvwz \leq w^2v^2+u^2z^2$, from which we get $(uv + wz)^2 \leq (u^2+w^2)(v^2+z^2)$ and then $(uv + wz) \leq \sqrt{(u^2 + w^2) (v^2 + z^2)}$, yeilding $$(u+v)^2 + (w+z)^2 \leq \left(\sqrt{u^2 + w^2} + \sqrt{v^2 + z^2}\right)^2.$$

I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't see why
$$(uv + wz) \leq \sqrt{(u^2 + w^2) (v^2 + z^2)} \implies (u+v)^2 + (w+z)^2 \leq \left(\sqrt{u^2 + w^2} + \sqrt{v^2 + z^2}\right)^2.$$

Any hints would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just multiply out, and follow your nose:
$$\left(\sqrt{u^2+w^2}+\sqrt{v^2+z^2}\right)^2
=u^2+v^2+w^2+z^2+2\sqrt{(u^2+w^2)(v^2+z^2)}
\ge u^2+v^2+w^2+z^2+2(uv+wz)=(u+v)^2+(w+z)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Just expand both terms:

$$(u+v)^2 + (w+z)^2 \leq \left(\sqrt{u^2 + w^2} + \sqrt{v^2 + z^2}\right)^2 
 \Leftrightarrow$$

$$u^2+2uv+v^2+w^2+2wz+z^2 \leq \sqrt{(u^2 + w^2)(v^2 + z^2)}+u^2+w^2+v^2+z^2\Leftrightarrow$$

$$uv+wz\le \sqrt{(u^2 + w^2)(v^2 + z^2)}$$